# how to add multiple command inside if statment

Tags: vbscript, secure-crt

my objective is to check if the switch prompt either ">" or "#" if prompt to ">" to send enable password then the command. if the switch prompt to "#"  send just the command. but some reason go to directly to the command with out checking the condition.

```
  `  result = crt.Screen.WaitForString ([">","#"])
                If (result=1) Then  
                crt.Screen.Send chr(13)
                crt.Screen.Send "XXXXX" & chr(13)
                crt.Screen.WaitForString "Password: "
                crt.Screen.Send "a" & chr(13)
                crt.Screen.WaitForString "#"
                End If
               '++++++++++Now Send the command ++++++++++
         crt.Screen.Send "sh ver" & chr(13)
         crt.Screen.WaitForString vbcr
             strReadScreen = crt.Screen.ReadString("#")`
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if the condition is checked it may fail or not, the command is always executed.
Try to check for '>" first, then make your special stuff ... then check for both and call command

```
if(==">"){
 // do stuff here
}
if(=="#" || ==">"){
 // send command
}
```

">" and "#" would mean result==1 or result==2 in your code.

Comment: thanks for the response, I got some idea from your suggestion and fix the problem.